# Rcov report index file wasn't found in jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rcov

I am trying to configure a rails project to jenkins. there are some test code. I am covering the test code using rcov. But when i build the project on jenkins , the following error was found.

```
Publishing rcov report...
rcov report index file wasn't found
```

In post build action i made the necessary steps.
 default directory for "Rcov report directory" is coverage/rcov

any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow the bellow step to get success:

```
jenkins_app/configure/
```

Then you need to go `Post-build Actions` and then go `Publish Rcov report`

You will see `Rcov report directory` text field and then fill the text box value by  `coverage/rcov`

Also before do this you need to ensure that you have right gem in your gem file:

```
 #Gemfile

 gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
 gem 'simplecov-rcov'
```

And also configure your `spec/spec_helper.rb` like this:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

I hope then your issue will be fixed!

Comment: I added the configuration code to test/test_helper.rb instead of spec/spect_helper.rb.